# Vocales impares de una cadena en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola buenas estaba haciendo un codigo donde tengo ingresar un texto que contenga letras y números y pasar a mayusculas solo las vocales en las palabras impares. El resto debe estar en minusculas.
No me esta tomando el ultimo for para pasar las vocales a mayusculas.

Ejemplo:

texto = “Hoy es Viernes 15 de Octubre”.

Resultado: "hOy es vIErnEs 15 dE octubre"

```
texto = str(input())
texto = texto.lower()
vocales = "aeiou"

for i in range(len(texto)):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        resultado = ""
        for x in i:
            if texto[x] in vocales:
                resultado+= texto[x].upper()

print(resultado)
```

Comment: El segundo `for` está mal, no puedes iterar en un número, pero si en un rango, tal vez quisiste hacer `for x in range(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Mejor partir de cero:

```
palabras = input().lower().split()
```

Con esto ingresamos la frase, la pasamos toda a minúsculas y luego la dividimos obteniendo una lista de palabras.

```
salida = []
```

`salida` contendrá la lista de palabras transformadas de acuerdo a lo pedido.

Ahora vamos a recorrer la lista de palabras. En cada iteración miramos si la palabra es par (`i % 2` da cero):

- Si el palabra es par, recorremos la palabra letra por letra, preguntando si es vocal. En tal caso, se pasa a mayúsculas.
- Si es impar, no hacemos nada especial.

Luego agregamos la palabra a la salida.

```
for i in range(len(palabras)):
    palabra = palabras[i]
    if i % 2 == 0:
        nueva = []
        for letra in palabra:
            if letra in "aeiou":
                letra = letra.upper()
            nueva.append(letra)
        palabra = ''.join(nueva)
    salida.append(palabra)

print(salida)
```

#### Demo

```
palabras = input().lower().split()

salida = []
for i in range(len(palabras)):
    palabra = palabras[i]
    if i % 2 == 0:
        nueva = []
        for letra in palabra:
            if letra in "aeiou":
                letra = letra.upper()
            nueva.append(letra)
        palabra = ''.join(nueva)
    salida.append(palabra)

print(salida)
```

produce:

```
la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta
['lA', 'mona', 'jAcIntA', 'se', 'hA', 'puesto', 'UnA', 'cinta']


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Si pero creo que estan mal ubicadas las palabras de la frase en el enunciado

Comment: @ValentinoPugliese. Cierto ... la costumbre de contar los índices desde cero, no desde uno. Lo edito.

Comment: Bueno gracias!.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Sugerencia: `for i, w in enumerate(palabras):` y luego `palabra = w` en la primera línea del bucle.

Comment: Junto con el in range?

Answer (score 1):

1. Si semánticamente estás dividiendo entre palabras (una palabra sí
   una palabra no), es conveniente que un *ciclo-for* realice una
   iteración para cada palabra por separado.

```py
for i,word in enumerate(texto.split(' ')):
    # Código aquí
```

2. Puedes elegir si la palabra es par o impar usando el residuo de
   dividir por dos

```py
i % 2
```

3. También puedes remplazar las vocales utilizando `objeto.translate()` con `str.maketrans('aeiou','AEIOU')`
   para evitar recorrer cada character en un *ciclo-for* adicional`
4. Por último, debes unir las palabras separadas en una lista, usando:

```py
' '.join(resultado)
```

##### Código final

```py
texto = "Hoy es Viernes 15 de Octubre"
texto = texto.lower()
vocales = "aeiou"

vowel_trans = str.maketrans('aeiou','AEIOU')

resultado = []
for i,word in enumerate(texto.split(' ')):
    if i % 2:
        # indice par
        resultado.append(word)
    else:
        # indice impar
        resultado.append(word.translate(vowel_trans))

print(' '.join(resultado))
```

**Alternativa:** Se puede reducir a una línea de código usando *list-comprehension*:

```py
texto = "Hoy es Viernes 15 de Octubre"
texto = texto.lower()
vocales = "aeiou"

vowel_trans = str.maketrans('aeiou','AEIOU')

print(' '.join([word.translate(vowel_trans) if not i % 2 else word for i,word in enumerate(texto.split(' '))]))
```

Salida:

```
hOy es vIErnEs 15 dE octubre
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.